# Is macbook pro 15 inch over-heating fixed?

Tags: macbook-pro

I want to buy a macbook pro 15 inch with i9 processor but I have heard that it has unacceptable over-heating problem. To what extent is this true? and is the problem likely going to get fixed? or am I better off to wait for next year where the issue is completely resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I think that overheating problem w i9 addressed by Apple through a software update:  https://www.businessinsider.com/apple-software-update-macbook-pro-core-i9-overheating-2018-7
Cheers